# Correctly access query parameters inside a System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, .net, http, url, url-routing

**Given**, a `HttpRequestMessage`,

- intercepted by the `System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler`'s `SendAsync` method
- resulting from a query to `http://example.com/api/redirect?resource=aa9f2dcb-82f4-88dc-c716-dd71a1ac3802&type=x-application%2fx-share%2bjson`

Calling `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions`'s `GetQueryNameValuePairs()` method on the provided `request` will yield a broken value for `type`.

```
public class MyHandler : System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var typeStr = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Skip(1).First().Value;
        // fails .    "x-application/share json" == typeStr 
        Assert.IsTrue("x-application/share+json",   typeStr); 
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

The `HttpRequestMessage`'s `.RequestUri` property value is `http://example.com/api/redirect?resource=aa9f2dcb-82f4-88dc-c716-dd71a1ac3802&type=x-application/x-share+json` (the query parameters have been URL decoded).

Neither encoding or decoding before or after the parse call will work because `/` and `+` are for some reason in different "states of encoding" when passed in from ASP.NET API. Using `HttpUtility` to parse the URL and calling `queryValues.ToString()` provides a hint to why this is an issue.

```
var queryValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.RequestUri.Query);
queryValues.ToString() == "resource=aa9f2dcb-82f4-88dc-c716-dd71a1ac3802&type=x-application%2fx-share+json"
```

Note that in `type=x-application%2fx-share+json` `/` is `%2f` and `+` is still `+` (different "states of encoding").

**Alternatives**

Url decoding the resulting value reinserts the `+` but converts `/` to `%2f`.

```
var urlEncodedResult = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(typeString);
// urlEncodedResult == "x-application%2fx-share+json"
```

Url encoding the query string before calling `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`

```
var urlEncodedQuery = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(uri.Query);
// urlEncodedQuery == %3fresource%3daa9f2dcb-82f4-88dc-c716-dd71a1ac3802%26type%3dx-application%2fx-share%2bjson 
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(urlEncodedQuery)["type"] // null
```

of course does not work because the query string's `&`s are now encoded.

Obviously some form of manual string parsing (regex, etc) would work. However, the goal here is to use the standard libraries.

**Question**: While this has been explained in various places on Stack Overflow, and some solutions have been offered, to the best of my knowledge there is no direct answer to the question: *Given an `HttpRequestMessage` in a `DelegatingHandler` what is a correct/reliable way to access the unencoded query parameters using builtin libraries?*

Comment: Can you give more details about where you notice the `RequestUri` returning a url containing `x-share json` instead of `x-share+json`? This [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ejr0dc) can't reproduce.

Comment: This issue is not with making the request. The issue is with receiving a `HttpRequestMessage` and trying to extract the parameters from the query. `HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetQueryNameValuePairs()` will return a collection where `type` will be `x-share json`.

Comment: I understood that; can you expand your question with the code where and how you receive such a request. The `uri` example shown, isn't representative as it gets initialized with the decoded url string.

Comment: I have constructed a `HttpRequestMessage` from which the `Uri` is not extracted. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Not all querystring arguments in `urlString` are url-encoded; the value for argument `x` should be `x-application%2fx-share%2bjson` instead of `x-application/x-share+json`; eg. via `var urlString = "http://example.com/api/redirect?resource=aa9f2dcb-82f4-88dc-c716-dd71a1ac3802&type=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode("x-application/fx-share+bjson");`.
A `HttpRequestMessage` instantiated with a correct url-string, will have a `RequestUri` return `x-application/x-share+json` for parameter `x`. The issue here is in the url passed to `HttpRequestMessage`, not the parsing via `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. The issue is not with `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` or `HttpRequestMessageExtensions.GetQueryNameValuePairs`. The issue is with the `HttpRequestMessage` passed in from ASP.NET API. I have updated the question to include this.

Comment: I appreciate the info update. What's your hosting environment (asp.net (core), owin, IIS, self-hosted)? I don't succeed in reproducing in a regular asp.net mvc/webapi setup; `RequestUri` in `MyHandler` above returns expected `x-application/share+json` :/ I use Fiddler to post to a url containing `?resource=aa9f2dcb-82f4-88dc-c716-dd71a1ac3802&type=x-application%2fx-share%2bjson`

Comment: IIS Express, .NET Framework 4.6.1